# html2canvas not working at all

Tags: html2canvas

Here is the code which isn't working. Basically I'm allowing the user to edit some text in the div and then display its screenshot. Can someone please tell why is it not working?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <title>Poster</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main_image">
    <img src="image.jpg" id= "image"/>
    <div id="user_text">IT IS TOTALLY AWESOME</div>
  </div>
  <div id="edit_text_box">
    <textarea id="user_input" placeholder="Your text here.." rows="2" cols="30" ></textarea>
    <div id="change_size">
      <span style="float: left;">FONT-SIZE : </span>
      <button id="decrease_size">-</button>
      <button id="increase_size">+</button>
    </div>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      html2canvas( [ document.body ], {
      onrendered: function( canvas ) {
        document.body.appendChild( canvas );
      }
    });
  };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/edit_text.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit and it works:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <title>Poster</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var Submit = function() {
      html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
      });
  };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main_image">
    <img src="image.jpg" id= "image"/>
    <div id="user_text">IT IS TOTALLY AWESOME</div>
  </div>
  <div id="edit_text_box">
    <textarea id="user_input" placeholder="Your text here.." rows="2" cols="30" ></textarea>
    <div id="change_size">
      <span style="float: left;">FONT-SIZE : </span>
      <button id="decrease_size">-</button>
      <button id="increase_size">+</button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="Submit();" >Submit</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/edit_text.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

First, I added html2canvas JavaScript file (`<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>`). You can download it at https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js and put that file to the same folder as your HTML. Apparently, you are trying to create something like a form, but there's no `form` tag in your code. You can call html2canvas either when you submit a form (you have to add `<form>` then) or using `onclick` attribute of a `button`. I changed your `submit` input element to `button` and bind `Submit` method to its `onclick` attribute. When user clicks the button, screenshot appears below the form.

Comment: Thank you so very much man ! Ya actually I had added that onClick event earlier but I experimented a lot after that to make it work so that's why it isn't here.So basically I had to link that file ! Will keep that in mind. You saved me !

Answer (score 0):

```
Just use this code



document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector('.specific'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      return Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
    }
  });
});
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-default {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: inherit;
}
h1 small {
  font-size: 65%;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #777;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.specific {
  background-color: #fff;
}
p a {
  padding: 5px;
}
<script src="https://superal.github.io/canvas2image/canvas2image.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div class="specific">
  <h1>Click to Take a Screenshot & Download it! <small>using html2canvas.js + canvas2image.js</small></h1> 
  <p>This is a simple demo.</p>
  <p>Use html2canvas.js to take a screenshot of a specific div and then use canvas2image.js to download the screenshot as an image locally to your filesystem.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Take a Screenshot!</button>
  <p>References: <a href="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/">html2canvas.js</a><a href="https://github.com/SuperAL/canvas2image">canvas2image.js</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).