# How to get screenshot on dynamic image url path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

how to  get screenshot on particular div using html2canvas to dynamic url path. when we used html2canvas static image path screenshot capture full image. when we used dynamic url img path div area show black. how to resolve it. if anyone have solution please help me.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your efforts so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. What is in the console if anything?

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820009/html2canvas-not-working-at-all

Comment: use image contstructor for dynamic images.